# Is there a way to remove the reading password from PDF file?

Tags: pdf, passwords

So, I have a few confidential PDF files that I need to open, but they are reading-protected (not sure if that's the term, I can't read them without the password). I don't know this password. Is there any way to either remove/bypass this password or are there any tools for brute-forcing it?

Comment: Not knowing the password of password protected files usually means you are not allowed to read them. Consider asking the author for the password.

Comment: For context: My mother got an email from a bank telling her they lent some money to a business registered on her name. My mother doesn't recognise this and when she asked the bank, they could only send a contract (or whatever it is) in a password-protected email and told her that the number of the business (unique 8-digit number given to each business) is the password. She wants to find out what business this is and contact them.

Comment: I think that sounds like she should ask a lawyer to act on her behalf and require the bank to provide readable information, in court if necessary.